# Форвард сообщений Telegram ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
token = "token"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(m):
    msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Какой-то текст")
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Тест', 'Тест']])
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Тест']])
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, tudun)
def tudun(m):
    if m.text == 'Отправить':
        bot.forward_message('14616464', '-16414640451513', m.message_id)
```

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" бот пересылал последнее сообщение на канал. В данный момент выходит ошибка(message to forward not found(сообщение для пересылки не найдено)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь была ошибка
`bot.forward_message('14616464', '-16414640451513', m.message_id)`

Так всё заработало`bot.forward_message(message.chat.id, '-1001304645013', '2')`

Первое - это чат куда нужно переотправлять сообщение, второе куда нужно отправлять сообщение и третье - это id самого сообщения